# UISegmentedControl with image returns null for titleForSegmentAtIndex

Tags: ios, ipad, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a segmented control where i have 4 segments. Three of them have labels and one has image.
When i use titleForSegmentAtIndex, it returns fine text for the first three but for image segment it retuns null.
Any ideas why?

```
NSArray *segmentArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"One", @"Two", @"Three",[UIImage imageNamed:IMAGE_ANY_NUMBER], nil];
self.timeSegments = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:segmentArray];
    self.timeSegments.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0x77/255.0 green:0x77/255.0 blue:0x77/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    self.timeSegments.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0xFB/255.0 green:0xFB/255.0 blue:0xFB/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    [self addSubview:self.segmentArray];
```

Comment: I think you need to set title as well as image for 4th segment. and set title color is clear so you can see only image as par you expected result. and you also get title for 4th segment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

titleForSegmentAtIndex isn't going to return a title if you haven't set one. You will need to use imageForSegmentAtIndex instead.

Do you have a code snippet we can see?

Comment: Ah using imageForSegmentAtIndex worked for me :) Thanks